# Supply lambda function as string to call_user_func?

Tags: php

I would like to supply "call_user_func" with a lambda function as shown below. Unfortunately, it throws a fatal error which is also shown below.
Is it possible to have a setup like this and supply a lambda function as a string to "call_user_func"?

```
<?php
$hook = "call_user_func";
$f = 'function ($a, $b) { echo "..."; }';
$a1 = "1";
$a2 = "2";
$res = $hook($f, $a1, $a2);
?>
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, function "function ($a, $b) { echo "..."; }" not found or invalid function name in ...:6
> Stack trace:
> #0 {main}
> thrown in ... on line 6

**[UPDATE]**
By removing the quotation marks around $f the example does work. However, what if $f is supplied from external?

```
<?php
$hook = "call_user_func";
$f = $_GET['f_ex'];       # function ($a, $b) { echo "..."; }
$a1 = "1";
$a2 = "2";
$res = $hook($f, $a1, $a2);
?>
```

Comment: Take the quotes off the definition of `$f`.

Comment: ^^^ as per above: https://3v4l.org/6AnXV . In your original code $f is a string, not a function. Why would you want it as a string?

Comment: What if $f is not defined in the code like in my example but is supplied as user input (e.g. $_POST variable or read from a file)?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest allowing user-supplied code from a POST request to be executed. It could contain anything, and thus opens up a pile of security risks. What are you trying to achieve with this idea, and why?

Comment: @ADyson I wondered if the code above is a security risk. Obviously it would be if user-supplied code could be executed. However, at the moment it at least does not seem like I can supply a lambda function via $f that is used by "call_user_func" unless I modify the code and for example include an "eval" as suggested by Barmar in his answer.

Comment: Well yeah obviously right _now_ it's not a risk because it doesn't work, but the point was that you are asking how to achieve it and make the idea work. And at the point you achieve it then obviously it becomes a risk. So again...why do you want to make that possible?

Comment: Even if it's just a toy project you do for fun and you don't think that being hacked is a big deal, you'll have to host it somewhere, and I'm sure your hosting provider will not be amused. Hacked sites can be used to mine crypto or attack other sites, causing resource drain and legal issues.

Comment: I am dealing with code similar to the one shown by me and I wonder if it is possible to execute some code that can cause security issues. So it is not my code and I cannot change it. I can supply a function name and this function gets the two strings "1" and "2". My thought process was to call a lambda function but this does not seem to work in php without changing the code.

Comment: Sorry it's not really clear what you mean. You are telling us that your real question is about some code which is not the same as what you showed in the question? Then we are probably wasting our time. Please provide a [mre] of the real scenario.

Comment: `I can supply a function name`..ah, so you send the name of a function which already exists in the codebase, and then PHP executes that function? That is much safer, and if that is all it will respond to, then you probably cannot break it. But we'd have a better idea if you showed us relevant bits of the real-life code.

Comment: The code is very similar to the one above but it is not my code and I cannot change it. So you are not wasting your time. I am aware of potential security implications but with the code shown it does not seem like one can cause something severe like code execution through lambda functions through the $_GET variable. The only option is to run a php function with the two string arguments "1" and "2". So not great but not code execution unless someone has another idea. When I saw the code for the first time my worry was that code execution is possible that leads to RCE.

Comment: `it is not my code and I cannot change it.`...that isn't particularly relevant. If you're asking if it's possible to break it with certain input values and cause a security issue, then we don't need or want to change it. But we _do_ need to see it. And "similar" is not "the same". Small details can be important. Security issues have been known to be caused by single characters missing from the relevant place. So if you want to know if code X is secure, then showing us code Y instead is not useful, sorry.

Comment: Take the code that I present above as a minimal reproducible example. I was worried that it is possible to get code execution through the lambda approach. If you have other ideas your are welcome to step forward. The minimal reproducible example is there since I first updated the post yesterday. It is not my question if it is a good idea to use the code and whether or not I should use it but if it can be exploited the way it is right now.

Comment: I see. Well, with the _code you have presented_ then no, it can't be exploited by passing executable PHP code within the `$f` string. But since you're saying it's not identical to the real code (and bear in mind that we don't know what the specific differences are), no-one can here can say, definitively, that there is no way to exploit the original. I agree it's probably unlikely that there is a significant difference which would change the result, but no-one in their right mind would actually sign off on that without full sight of the real code which is being used in production.

Answer (score 1):

Use `eval()` to execute code supplied in a string.

```
$hook = "call_user_func";
eval("\$f = {$_GET['f_ex']};")
$a1 = "1";
$a2 = "2";
$res = $hook($f, $a1, $a2);
```

While it's generally dangerous to use `eval()` with code supplied externally, since the whole point of this is to execute that code, that concern is not an issue in this case. Allowing clients to supply the function to execute is a problem to begin with.

Comment: Security implications aside, but it seems like it is not possible to use my updated code from above and supply a lambda function or something similar to $f via $_GET/$_POST/... without adjusting the remaining code as you did with the eval function for example.

Comment: So you're not asking how to fix the code, you're asking if the original code is susceptible to this exploit?